# Is there a way to compare two tabs of data and place Difference at end of one of the datasets

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I need to find a way to compare two spreadsheets and if there is a Differences, pull data from one sheet to the other.

Sheet1 has a list of all Dealers in my Zone.

Other Tabs in my workbook have participating dealers which may not be all of them.  I need to know who is missing on each tab other than Sheet1 which is the tab they will all be compared to.
I need to have the missing dealers shown in the same column as the participating only at the end.

```
Sheet1       Accord 2DR 4C
All DLRS.    PARTICIPATING
206675       206675
207475       206600
206246       207475
207326       TOTAL
206600       TOTAL
207775       207775

             **MISSING DLRS.**  
             207326  
             206246
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a new worksheet, enter the following data (leave column B empty):
A1: 1   B1:     C1: 3
A2: 2   B2:     C2: 5
A3: 3   B3:     C3: 8
A4: 4   B4:     C4: 2
A5: 5   B5:     C5: 0

Type the following formula in cell B1:
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A1,$C$1:$C$5,0)),"",A1)
Select cells B1:B5.
In Microsoft Office Excel 2003 and in earlier versions of Excel, point to Fill on the Edit menu, and then click Down.

In Microsoft Office Excel 2007, click Fill in the Editing group, and then click Down.

The duplicate numbers are displayed in column B, as in the following example:
   A1: 1   B1:     C1: 3
   A2: 2   B2: 2   C2: 5
   A3: 3   B3: 3   C3: 8
   A4: 4   B4:     C4: 2
   A5: 5   B5: 5   C5: 0

Reference: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/213367/en-us

Col 1   Col 2
1   3
2
3   2
4   6   4
5   1   5
6

=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A2,B2:B7,0)),A2,"")

This matches the contents of the first column and prints the items missing in the 2nd.

Unfortunately, the table formatting is lost in this textbox.

Comment: mulick  I don't understand how you want the first set of data entered.  Can you provide an example?  I have entered the formula in Cell B1 as you suggested.

Comment: I was able to click on your reference link but found that it brings back duplicates.  I am not looking for the duplicates.  I need to know which of the dealer numbers are missing based on the entire list of dealer numbers on tab Sheet1.  I need to know what missing and have that result be placed under the list of Accord 2DR 4C.  The Accord 2DR 4C list is a list of Attending Dealers.  Sheet1 has the list of all those that Should have attended.  I need to know who is missing as in the example above.

Comment: Still, if you can find duplicates, you can inverse the reasoning in the IF to find non-duplicates. @Ayan, you can format yourself at the best of your abilities. Consult the [markdown editing help](http://superuser.com/help/formatting).

Comment: "=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A2,B2:B7,0)),A2,"")"  This is to find the non-duplicates only.

I am not able to post a table in a table format. And I can't post a picture since I am short on credits. :(

Answer (score 0):

Following the example given on [Microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/213367/en-us) the ***only*** change you need to do is the following:

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A1,$C$1:$C$5,0)),A1,"")
```

Note the reversed order of the arguments. If the matching function gives an error, it is because it couldn't find a match. If that verifies, write the number that is missing. If not, keep blank.

I know it isn't what you wanted specifically, but it is easy. I assume you could filter the blanks using the filter options in Excel, but that may be slightly more complicated.

Comment: I need to compare the contents of Sheet1 range A1:A129 with a tab called Accord 2DR 4C range C8:C147.  There are many columns of information in Accord 2DR 4C after column C so the result needs to post right back to column C in tab Accord.  I want to use range C147:C190.  I want only to have the difference between the two tabs column information post to C147:C190 on tab Accord 2DR 4C not in Sheet1.

Comment: Just place this formula on C148 (on the Accord 2DR 4C sheet), drag down, and adapt the `$C$1:$C$5` to the range you mentioned existing on Accord 2DR 4C and the A1 to Sheet1. More we couldn't possibly tell you (as we don't have access to your data); try for yourself and adapt to the situation.

Comment: This works very well!  It brings back my information.  Now how do I get it to post the information at the top of this area?  In other words what is happening is it returns blanks for all those that match until the missing information shows up which means my missing data may be way down on the list under a bunch of blanks.  I need them showing together without blanks.I might be able to post the preceeding results in columns AA if there is a formula that will gather only my results without the blanks and post them to C 148????

Comment: Sorry I forgot to address my comment to you.  I am almost there.  I just need to get rid of the blanks so if I post your formula in another column then maybe I can group the results without blanks beginning in C148?

Comment: Like I said, you can use the filter options in Excel ([relevant link](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/filter-data-in-an-excel-table-HA102840028.aspx)) to filter the non-blank cells.

Comment: The data needs to be brought without the blanks directly under the rest of my data so I can't filter.  As in the example at the beginning of this I would not be able to run a filter without it effecting the rest of the column.

Comment: You can, assuming you only selected the cells that mattered to you (i.e. the different cells) and as long as there exists a header cell.